# Improving quality of aztec barcode before reading using zxing

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, zxing, aztec-barcode

I'm trying to decode aztec codes from images using zxing library.

Images looks more or less like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ybYb.jpg

So far my results are quite random.

I've tried a few image processing actions using imagemagick such as:

```
convert -brightness-contrast 50x20 in.png out.png
```

```
convert -colorspace Gray in.png out.png
```

And there was improvement but still most of codes fails to decode.

What specific image preprocessing actions should I do for such barcodes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try -lat (local area threshold) in Imagemagick. For example:

Input:

[image]

```
convert barcode.png -colorspace gray -negate -lat 20x20+10% -negate result.png
```

[image]

You can improve that a little by adding -morphology close:

```
convert barcode.png -colorspace gray -negate -lat 20x20+10% -negate -morphology open diamond:1 result2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, but there is no improvement, codes look even worse like this: https://imgur.com/a/VZJ4hDh

Comment: I do not think you have enough resolution to make any improvements. You needed to scan the bar code at a higher density.